# Override contrib Disqus behavior settings

Tags: 8, javascript

I want to override a contrib module's library setting that is being attached to page using `hook_js_settings_alter()`. But, I am unable to change the `setting` that is being called in js.

Here is the code that is being called in Disqus module Element:

```
$element['#attached']['library'][] = 'disqus/disqus';
$element['#attached']['drupalSettings']['disqus'] = $disqus;
```

I want to override settings in `$disqus` that is being called in Disqus.js

```
Drupal.behaviors.disqus = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // Load the Disqus comments.
    if (settings.disqus || false) {
```

I could override this element with `hook_element_info_alter`, but is there a way to override the above `settings.disqus` using other hooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`hook_js_settings_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_js_settings_alter/8.2.x) Something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_js_settings_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_js_settings_alter(array &$settings, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  if (isset($settings['disqus'])){
    // Change settings here 
    $new_disqus_settings = [];
    $settings['disqus'] = $new_disqus_settings;
  }
}
```

Comment: Since, Disqus is rendering field using Element and using lazy_builder to render the element, I am unable to get those settings. Any other help?